# How to provide functions that cannot be found at linking?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, linker, static-linking

When I try to compile my app, I get two errors:

> > $ g++ -static -emit-swf -o CloudClient.swf  -I../boost/boost_libraries/install-dir/include -I../ffm
> >         peg-1.0/bin/include -L../boost/boost_libraries/install-dir/lib -L../ffmpeg-1.0/bin/lib     timer.o
> >             audio_encoder.o     audio_generator.o     video_encoder.o     video_generator_rainbow.o     sim
> >         ple_synchronizer.o     multiplexer.o     transmitter.o     graph_runner.o     cloud_client.o  -lswscale -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lboost_system     -lboost_date_time     -lboost_thread     -pthread -lm

```
../ffmpeg-1.0/bin/lib/libswscale.a: error: undefined reference to 'exp'
../ffmpeg-1.0/bin/lib/libavcodec.a: error: undefined reference to 'log'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If `log` and `exp` are my problem and if anywhere I put `-lm` it does not help I wonder how to literally create my own stubs instead `exp` and `log` and link my libs with them? ....

Comment: Just create empty functions with the matching signatures?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey: it's fine. From `man gcc`: `-pthread: Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library. This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would implement them in a C file (than gets compiled by a C compiler, not a C++ compiler), or in a C++ file and give then extern "C" linkage. For example:

```
extern "C" double log(double x)
{
    // ...
}
```

Obviously it would be better for you to solve the link problem though. You shouldn't have to provide your own versions of standard C library routines.

Comment: Is it possible to get which function overload was used in the library?

Comment: @myWallJSON The C++ library provides three overloads (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/log). However, C doesn't have overloading. It only has the `double` version. I assume that ffmpeg is written in C, therefore you don't have to provide any overloads (even if you did, C code wouldn't be able to use them; overloading only works with C++ linkage. You can't have overloads of `extern "C"` functions.)